# Postgres, How to add a column generated from other tables to an existing table?

Tags: postgresql

I've got three tables. Table A has a column of start dates, table B (which is a bridge table) has a column of end dates, and table C has a column of costs. I want to add a new column to table B with the values of ((end - start) * cost). I've tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE b_table ADD COLUMN
    b_totalcost DECIMAL (6,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    ((b.b_enddate:: DATE - a.a_startdate::DATE) * c.c_cost
    FROM a_table a, b_table b, c_table c
    WHERE a.a_id = b.a_id AND c.c_id = b.c_id
    ) AS DECIMAL (6,2)
STORED;
```

I know it's something wrong with the FROM statement, but I'm very new to Postgres, and not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You cannot refer to other tables for a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html). if you want that info you could create a [VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createview.html)

Comment: Can I then store that VIEW as a column? I'd like to be able to keep it in table B, if I can

Comment: The question is unclear because it is unknow why you do store 'start date'  in a different table then 'end date'. Also costs will be made at a specific date, or period. Can you add info on what you are trying to do, and hopefully there are some database guru's here who can explain what the a good way of doing that is.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It is unclear why the information is spread over several tables, and what the cardinality is between those tables.